# Why would IE9 media queries not respond until the page is almost 20px within range?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, media-queries

I have media queries that work fine in all browsers that accept MQ. However, in IE9 it won't respond until I'm within the range of the query. For example my 959 - 768 wont respond until I'm 942px in. Between 959 and 941 I have a horizontal scroll bar.

I've looked into padding and margins but that doesn't seem to be the issue (could be wrong). Anyone know of any IE bugs that cause this or have seen it before and fixed the issue?

Thanks, guys!

--- EDIT ---

To be clear this seems to happen on every breakpoint not just the 959

Comment: Can you post your CSS?

Comment: I would love to but the insanity that I'm having to work though is too much to post. I can say I'm using the skeleton framework though.

Comment: added more info to the question (also, I agree, the css would help but posting it would give you jus as much of a headache as it's giving me)

Comment: If you could make a http://jsfiddle.net it could be of some help.

Comment: @rcdmk You're right, it would be helpful and if the css alone wasn't about 4000lines long and was organized, I would jsfiddle it. But I've inherited a bit of a mess. I'ved every bug but this one IE issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the answer and ended up hiding the overflow on IE9 with a conditional style sheet. Please note this is almost never a good solution but I was pressed for time and it was a last resort.